# Changing value of Enum in C# in an Excel download

Tags: c#, enums

There is a list of objects being passed to an excel service to download in excel.

One of the properties on that object is `DayOftheWeek`. `DayOftheWeek` is an enum of `Weekdays`.

```
public enum Weekdays
{
  Monday = 1,
  Tuesday = 2,
  ...etc.
}
```

In some business logic, the objective is to cell value of the downloaded excel file based on the value of the enum.

So,

```
if (myObject.DayOftheWeek == Weekdays.Tuesday)
{
   // the value in the downloaded excel should not be "Tuesday" but "xyz"...
}
// pass list of objects to excel service
```

Any assistance?

Comment: You can't. And you shouldn't even display directly enum names to the user. What happens if you want to sell your program to spanish speaking persons? Or if you have enum values that are two words? `enum HowMany { Once, Twice, ThreeTimes }`

Comment: You have to work backwards. You need a dictionary enum value->string of description, that you'll put somewhere, and you can modify it (like `public static readonly Dictionary<Weekdays, string>`) I would normally say it is horrible, because you have a global state that anyone can change, but in the end "not my code".

Comment: Yeah. I'm new to the project and this is what they gave me as a requirement. I could add another Enum option but...I'm not sure what that will break.

Comment: I doubt that the requirement is to change the enum, which is comprised of constants, so that wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: No, the requirement is to change what the enum says on the UI based on a condition. So instead of it saying "Tuesday", they want it to say "xyz..." And I can't create a new enum either.

Comment: @J.G.Sable so why are you trying to change the enum? This is UI logic based on a value. You are terribly confused. You have to set that text to whatever the display control is, web or desktop.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't clear. I didn't mean UI, this is for an excel service. Let me update the post.

Comment: you mean something like `var mything = (myObject.DayOftheWeek == Weekdays.Tuesday) ? "Tuesday" :"xyz";`

Comment: or if you want to check them all, something like `var mything = (myObject.DayOftheWeek >= DayOfWeek.Monday && myObject.DayOftheWeek <= DayOfWeek.Friday) ? "some weekday" :"xyz";`
    }

Answer (score 0):

As the [msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) for enums states:

> An enumeration type (or enum type) is a value type defined by a set of named constants of the underlying integral numeric type.

So enums are just numeric constants that you give a label to. The value of them cannot be changed and the name given to it is just a label to help you read and understand what that value means.

-- Just saw the edit --

You still cannot change the property myObject.DayOfTheWeek to become something that doesn't exist within the enum list. If that property is meant to be changed to be something different not defined within the enum, then that myObject.DayOfTheWeek should be a string instead. Enums should be used when you only want to use the data within the enum and not any random kind of data.

If you make that change, then you can rewrite your logic to look like this:

```
if (myObject.DayOftheWeek.Equals(Weekdays.Tuesday.ToString(), StringCompairson.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
   // the value in the downloaded excel should not be "Tuesday" but "xyz"...
   myObject.DayOfTheWeek = "xyz";
}
// pass list of objects to excel service
```

Comment: I tried this, but because DayOfTheWeek is an enum, it won't let me assign a string value to it.

Comment: @J.G.Sable Can you change the datatype of DaysOfTheWeek to a string?

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the enum or the original object. My only option I believe is a dto of some kind that mirrors the original object except for this one property. Map the original object to the dto, and send a list of dtos to the excel service. Because I can use .toString on myObject.DayOftheWeek to perserve all other items in the list of myObjects